# How to configure CustomAuditEventRepository for auditing on a xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jhipster, hibernate-envers

I have a very old java application (servlet/jsp) and I'm modernizing it.

I have a requirement to add audit trail on the models.

I'm trying to use JHipster `CustomAuditEventRepository`, but I don't have all spring boot configured yet.

Spring and hibernate are configured via spring-config.xml
My class looks like this:

```
@Repository
public class CustomAuditEventRepository implements AuditEventRepository
```

I need to add this on the xml somehow.